Why doesn’t $\bigcap_{n=1}^{N} I_n \neq \emptyset $ for all $N$ entail $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n \neq \emptyset$?
I have a question about an exercise in Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis. This specific exercise in Abbott has been discussed before on the website. But I have a question about a particular proof attempt for this exercise that I believe previous questions and answers do not address.
Exercise 1.4.8.d asks us to either prove the following object doesn't exist or give an example of it:
A sequence of closed, bounded (not necessarily nested) intervals $I_1,I_2,I_3…$ with the property that
$\bigcap_{n=1}^{N} I_n \neq \emptyset $ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, but $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n = \emptyset$.
My question is, is it not the case that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{N} I_n \neq \emptyset $ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ immediately entails $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n \neq \emptyset$? Why isn't the former property holding for all $n$ and $\mathbb{N}$ having no upper bound sufficient work for the latter? This is what I don’t see other questions about this exercise cover.
As a comparison, consider earlier in this section when Abbott proves the nested interval property. (Page 20 here.) The proof proceeds by using the axiom of completeness to argue that, for an infinite sequence of closed nested intervals $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 \supseteq \ldots$, $\sup A$ lies within all $I_n$, where $A$ is the set of all left-endpoints of the $I_n$. Then, once he establishes $\sup A \in I_n$ for any choice of $n$, he immediately concludes $\sup A \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$. So, if, in that instance, we can conclude from the property holding for all $n$ that it holds for infinity, why can't we do that here?
But the entailment I'm talking about seems to be doing the same kind of thing.
Nobody seems to do this, actually. They instead use more complicated arguments, and that makes me think I am missing something. But I don't know why this immediate entailment doesn't go through or why it doesn't work in this situation but does work in Abbott's proof.

If, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $I_n={n,n+1,n+2,\ldots}$, then, for each $N\in\Bbb N$, $\bigcap_{n=1}^NI_n={N,N+1,\ldots}\ne\emptyset$. However, $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n=\emptyset$.

@JoséCarlosSantos I see the issue, thanks.
